# pyPDF merging and displaying as httpresponse through django

Tags: django, pdf, django-admin, pypdf

I'm having trouble incorporating pyPDF logic to merge two pdf files into my django site. I have written code that works to merge files when run in a python file on the local server(but I need to explicitly identify which files to merge:

```
from pyPdf import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter

output = PdfFileWriter()
input1 = PdfFileReader(file("abc_form0.pdf", "rb"))
input2 = PdfFileReader(file("abc_form1.pdf", "rb"))
total_pages = input1.getNumPages()
total_pages1 = input2.getNumPages()

for page in xrange(total_pages):
    output.addPage(input1.getPage(page))

for page in xrange(total_pages1):
    output.addPage(input2.getPage(page))


outputStream = file("output.pdf", "wb")
output.write(outputStream)
outputStream.close()
```

This code (from my django site) works to display a single PDF. However, when more than one PDF is selected, only the final PDF selected displays, hence the need to integrate pyPDF to create one file containing all requested files.

```
class ABCAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    actions = ['print_selected_pdf']

    def create_pdf(self, request, queryset):
        response = HttpResponse(mimetype="application/pdf")
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=form.pdf'
        for obj in queryset:
            response.write(obj.form)
            ABC.objects.filter(pk=obj.pk).update(user=request.user,pdf_printed="1",request_time=time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"),request_date=datetime.datetime.today())
            return response

    def print_selected_pdf(self, request, queryset):
        # prints the pdfs for those that are selected,
        # regardless if the pdf_printed field is true or false
        qs = queryset.filter(pdf_printed__exact=0)
        return self.create_pdf(request, qs)
```

I'm struggling with finding a way to combine these two methods. What I have tried is the following, but get an IO error [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'obj.form'. So it is not reading in obj.form - I need to find a way for it to read in these objects correctly. Anyway, this is what I've tried.

```
def create_pdf(self, request, queryset):
    response = HttpResponse(mimetype="application/pdf")
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=form.pdf'
    for obj in queryset:
        output = PdfFileWriter()
        input = PdfFileReader(file("obj.form","rb"))
        total_pages = input.getNumPages()
        for page in xrange(total_pages):
            output.addPage(input.GetPage(page))
        outputStream = file("output.pdf", "wb")
        response.write(outputStream)
        outputStream.close()
        ABC.objects.filter(pk=obj.pk).update(user=request.user,pdf_printed="1",request_time=time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"),request_date=datetime.datetime.today())
        return response

def print_selected_pdf(self, request, queryset):
    # prints the pdfs for those that are selected,
    # regardless if the pdf_printed field is true or false
    qs = queryset.filter(pdf_printed__exact=0)
    return self.create_pdf(request, qs)
```

As always, thanks for any help or tips you may be able to provide!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I used stringIO in the output stream to get around this. I also had to define each page of the PDF form to be added to the output. This works to iterate for any number of forms that I need to be requested.

```
def create_form(self, request, queryset):
    response = HttpResponse(mimetype="application/pdf")
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=form.pdf'
    output = PdfFileWriter()
    for obj in queryset:
        input = PdfFileReader(cStringIO.StringIO(obj.form))
        output.addPage(input.getPage(0))
        output.addPage(input.getPage(1))
        output.addPage(input.getPage(2))
        output.addPage(input.getPage(3))
        ABC_Self.objects.filter(pk=obj.pk).update(user=request.user,pdf_printed="1",request_time=time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"),request_date=datetime.datetime.today())
    outputStream = cStringIO.StringIO()
    output.write(outputStream)
    response.write(outputStream.getvalue())
    return response
```

Comment: In more modern version of django mimetype has been replaced by content_type

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is provide the full absolute path to your PDF files, e.g.

```
/home/joseph/form.pdf
```

or

```
c:/home/joseph/form.pdf
```

etc.